# How to split a string, store in a array and pass around a couple of functions in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I thought it would be pretty basic stuff. My C/C++ is rusty..  used it 14+ years back.. have been coding in perl, shell & python since and have a frustrating problem at hand in C code:

I have a string something like below in argv[7]:
   Min:Max:Both:Both

I want to break it using colon and store it into array. then I want to access a certain element of array, pass it to a string var and pass it around a couple of functions.. my problem is in defining the string array and then passing around the string across functions, which is pretty basic stuff in scripting languages

I am doing something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int iy = 0;
    char * y = (char *)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    char * tky = strtok(argv[7], ":");
      do {
        sprintf(y[iy],tky);
        printf("as string = %s and as array value = %s\n", tky, y[iy]);
        //printf("as string = %s \n", tky);
        iy++;
      } while((tky=strtok(NULL,":"))!=NULL);

      int measquant = 3;
      char colminmax[20];
        for(i=0; i<measquant; i++){
           sprintf(colminmax,"%s",y[i]);
           testfunction(colminmax);
         }
      return 0;
      }


      testfunction (char* dir){
              printf("dir is %s",dir);
         }
```

It is printing tky correctly and y[iy] as NULL
Then I am trying to assign and pass it as:

Please help what am I missing. I have searched numerous C/C++ help sites but unable to get to something as basic.

Comment: 14 years ago was ... 2003? But you're still writing C instead of C++ ... Anyway, please post the [minimal _complete_ example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem, these code fragments aren't as useful as they might be

Comment: There are many better ways to split strings in c++ than using the infamous `strtok()`.

Comment: Why is the question tagged with C++. I see only c-code!

Comment: @user0042: Your comment might be helpful if you named one or two.

Comment: The point was that strtok is infamous. It's almost always the worst.

Comment: For reference, even in 2003, you should have been using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)`<`[`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)`>` instead of this. And probably `std::string::find()` (or variants thereof) and `std::string::substr()` instead of  `strtok()`.

Comment: @sehe is right. But anyways [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286095/similar-function-to-javas-string-split-in-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c) are some better ways, but it's easy to find tons of good examples at google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Guys my main issue is with the: char * y = (char *)malloc(20*sizeof(char));  and          sprintf(yarr[iy],tky);
Am I doing anything wrong here. And then            sprintf(colminmax,"%s",y[i]); and       testfunction (char* dir){
are correct>

Comment: Apologies for tagging C++.. please have a look at C point of view. editing the tags

Comment: What is this expected to do: `sprintf(yarr[iy],tky);`? What is `yarr` and where is your format string? You print wrong types: `printf("as string = %s and as array value = %s\n", tky, y[iy]);` Here `y[iy]` is a single `char` but you use `"%s"` format specifier.

Comment: BTW: `main` is specified to return `int` type.

Comment: Thanks Gerhardh . Edited the mistakes. yarr is changed to y. I know there are some mistakes in the code which is why it is giving seg fault. In sprintf(y[iy],tky), my intent is to store the sting in tky into one element of the array y.  How do i correctly print it? and how to assign it correctly to colminmax

Comment: `y` is a pointer to 20 `char`s. You can use it to store a single string up to 19 characters. But you seem to use it as an array or strings. You should rethink that part.

Comment: everyone above except few like Gerhardh & John, i come back to SE after many years. I see less help and more hostility in these comments. An attitude of oneupmanship. You may be an expert in something & asker may be a novice. Help if you can or simply guide if you have time to write in a few words. Don't if you dont. but stay polite. humble? even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `char *y = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char))`, the `y` acts as *"array of characters"*. It can store a character up to 20 bytes long including the null-character. But your intention is to declare an *"array of strings"* instead.

You have to declare array of string instead (let's call it `arr`) and allocate memory for each element in the array. Then use `strcpy` to copy to that element. Or you can use `strdup` as shown in the example below.

You are accessing `argv[7]`, but you didn't check if `argc >= 7`. Note that the command line argument is already available as an array.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) 
{
    printf("argc = %d\n", argc);
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);

    int count = 0;
    char **arr = malloc(20 * sizeof(char*));

    //commented out for testing
    //if(argc < 7) return 0;
    //char *token = strtok(argv[7], ":");

    //use source instead of argv[7] for testing
    char source[] = "Min:Max:Both:Both";

    char *token = strtok(source, ":");
    while(token)
    {
        arr[count++] = strdup(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ":");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this on VS, and gcc, couldn't duplicate the error you are talking about. You must have changed something, I don't know what.

Comment: Thanks Barmak. It solved the problem. I had made a mistake earlier.

Comment: No, i accidentally declared a malloc of char instead of char* :(